# PHP Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, include

I have following setup.

**index.php**

```
   require_once "common.php";
   ...
```

**common.php**

```
   ...
   $obj = new MyClass;
   require_once "config.php"
   ...
```

**config.php**

```
   ...
   require_once "settings.php";
   ...
```

**settings.php**

```
   $obj->dostuff = true;
   ...
```

When i open **index.php** i get: **Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in settings.php on 3**

If i put `$obj->dostuff = true;` inside **config.php** it does not produce error message.

Can someone explain why i get this error? I am not asking how to fix it just understand why.

**EDIT:** My bad i had 2 config.php classes for each part of site and i only changed something in one of them leaving old include order in another now it works fine after it all loads in correct order.

Comment: What are the contents of `obj->dostuff`?

Comment: what is in settings.php line 3?

Comment: My bad it was not function() it was this on line 3 of **settings.php** `$obj->dostuff = true;`

Comment: is there anything in `MyClass`

Comment: in config.php are you putting `$obj->dostuff` directly before `require_once`?

Comment: I need to put `$obj->dostuff = true;` into **settings.php** that's the goal. in **config.php** wherever i place it i dont see strict standards error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $obj is meant to be a system wide globally accessible object, you can you use the singleton pattern to access from anywhere:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected static $_instance;

    static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

You can then create your methods in this class.  To get the object itself simply call:

```
$obj = MyClass::getInstance();
```

Additionally, if you just want to call one of its methods but theres no need to return anything:

```
MyClass::getInstance()->objectMethod();
```

I find this to be a very efficient way to organize integral singleton based system wide operations.

In practice, my project uses this to get configuration from anywhere in the system:

```
class syConfig
{
    protected static $_instance;

    private $_config;

    static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function load($xmlString)
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
        $this->_config = $xml;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->_config;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks a scope issue. In settings.php, the $obj is not accessible. PHP is creating new one from standard class, and giving you a warning. You can confirm it by putting

```
echo get_class($obj);
```

in Your settings.php, just after the line that is producing the error. If it echos "StdClass", then that is the case.

Are You sure the $obj is not created within a function/method ?

Comment: $obj is created like i said above with 1 line that run on script load